# setOnCheckedChangeListener variable problems

Tags: variables, button, toggle, global

I am trying to program an app that takes variables and calculates a score. On the click of a toggle button, variables are set to a simple number, eg, 1. I am trying to then export this number to a global variable. Afterwards, I want to simply add them together. My code however does not do this. So far no body has come with a solution.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class NewActivity1 extends Activity{

public static int exportNumber1;
public static int exportNumber2;

public void calc(){

    int sum;
    sum = exportNumber1 + exportNumber2;
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    textView.setText("The total is " + sum);
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_activity1);





    final ToggleButton atb1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    atb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean         isChecked) {

            int x = 0;

                if (isChecked)
                {
                    x = 1;
                }
                exportNumber1 = x;
                    }
                });

    final ToggleButton atb2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);  
    atb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            int x = 0;

                if (isChecked)
                {
                    x = 1;
                }
                exportNumber2 = x;
                    }
                });
```

}
}

Comment: Where does the actual calculation happen?

Comment: Well, its supposed to occur in the public void calc method Submersed. I just want to simply add the globals together and then print to the textView.

Comment: Yes, but how are your triggering this action?  It doesn't appear that you're every calling calc from the provided code.

Comment: Im not sure of the best way to do that.